# Painter's Partition in ascending least cost sets

Tags: algorithm, partition

Considering the [Painter's Partition Problem](http://articles.leetcode.com/the-painters-partition-problem-part-ii/) I am looking for a way to print the sets in ascending order after completing binary search.
Consider the following paradigm:
`1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 42`, divided into 4 sets. A correct solution is 
`1 1 1 1 1 1 1 | 1 | 1 | 42`.
I am trying to implement an ascending order solution that will print 
`1 | 1 | 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 | 42`, but I have not found any correct algorithm yet. My first thought was a greedy ( but wrong! ) algorithm by creating sets from right to left. Any ideas?